# LSTM model fitting issue

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a very simple LSTM model defined as

```
def get_lstm_model(shape_input, num_output):
    model = Sequential([
        layers.Input((shape_input, num_output)),
        layers.LSTM(64),
        layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu'),
        ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return model
```

The model definition works fine with the below lines

```
model_mlp = get_lstm_model(8,5)
model_mlp.summary()
```

Now when I am fitting the model, I get the error in response to this line

```
model_history = model_mlp.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2,
                                  epochs=500, batch_size=5000)
```

The error I get is:

```
"Input 0 of layer "lstm_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 8)"
For clarity, the shape of x_train is (2134,8), while the shape of y_train is (2134,5)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have indeed a problem inside the input dimensions. I'm not sure about what your data represents, so I've created two dummy numpy array for `x_train` and `y_train` of the desired shape.

From what I'm understanding you want an output shape of 5, so you have to specify that inside the last layer.

Regarding the input shape, the major problem is that the LSTM layer expects an input shape of three dimensions. From the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/) of LSTM:

> inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature]

So `x_train` must have a 3D shape: number of samples + two numbers like I show you below.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Sequential
import tensorflow as tf


def get_lstm_model(shape_input, num_output):
  model = keras.Sequential()
  model.add(layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(None, 8)))
  model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(layers.Dense(5))
  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics = ['accuracy'])
  return model

model_mlp = get_lstm_model(8,5)
print(model_mlp.summary())

x_train = np.zeros((2134, 8, 8))
y_train = np.zeros((2134, 5))
model_history = model_mlp.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=2, batch_size=5000)
```

The summary:

```
Model: "sequential_40"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm_33 (LSTM)              (None, 64)                18688     
                                                                 
 dense_43 (Dense)            (None, 32)                2080      
                                                                 
 dense_44 (Dense)            (None, 5)                 165       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 20,933
Trainable params: 20,933
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```